# Is it possible to exhaustively search through all Ethereum contracts in a local node

Tags: dapps

Currently building a stock exchange on Ethereum. Based on the current design, I have users creating individual buy orders as separate contracts tied to a central stock counter contract in the form of a list or mapping.

As certain operations on the exchange require the finding of the highest priced offer I was just wondering if it's possible for me to search through the list and sort the buy orders locally instead of running a function on the Ethereum blockchain which could possible cost alot of gas.

Any help provided would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can write a constant function in the EVM and call it locally; it won't cost any gas because you're not creating a transaction. Do you actually need to search the blockchain, or does your contract have what it needs to query all the associated contracts?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider a registry system as opposed to exhaustively searching a node.
ConsenSys just released Regis.nu for this reason. Also may want to look at other projects like EtherEx to see how they are doing it.

Comment: Regarding EtherEx: "In developing the platform, we've realized that placing an order (storing) costs a lot more gas than filling one. This in turn creates a type of inverted maker/taker model, which could have a large impact on the liquidity of the exchange. We are working on many different solutions to the gas imbalance of creating an order on EtherEx versus filling an order" https://etherex.org/blog/update-etherex